# nested RadAjaxPanel Telerik do not update

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, updatepanel

I create a RadAjaxPanel with some of inside controls.one of inside control is a nested radajax
with a TextBox and a button.both of radajaxpanel update mode are always(in code behind).
when i click on button in nested radajax parent radajax will be update an nested radajax will be hide!!Why?
I test this scenario with updatepanel and worked correct...

Markup:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" 
            onajaxsettingcreated="RadAjaxPanel1_AjaxSettingCreated1">

            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2" />
            <asp:Button  Text="but1" ID="but"  runat="server" onclick="but_Click" />

        <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel2" runat="server" Height="200px" 
                Width="300px" onajaxsettingcreated="RadAjaxPanel2_AjaxSettingCreated">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" />
            <asp:Button Text="but2" ID="but2" runat="server" onclick="but2_Click" />
        </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>

        </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt.Text = "ok";
            txt2.Text = "ok";
        }

        protected void but2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt.Text = "ok";
            txt2.Text = "ok";
        }

        protected void RadAjaxPanel1_AjaxSettingCreated1(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxSettingCreatedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.UpdatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Always;
        }
        protected void RadAjaxPanel2_AjaxSettingCreated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxSettingCreatedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.UpdatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Always;
        }
```

Comment: In fact, Telerik [explicitly states on their FAQ](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-faq.html) in answer to whether you can nest RadAjaxPanel: _"No. Telerik Support recommends you to revise the page logic and see if you can achieve the same behavior with RadAjaxManager and regular asp:Panels."_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to have a `RadAjaxPanel` nested inside of another `RadAjaxPanel`. I can't see anything in your code that warrants it either, so the easiest solution would be to remove it.

If you want to have more control over which controls are AJAX driven, I would suggest using the `RadAjaxManager` instead:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="AjaxManager" runat="server" UpdatePanelsRenderMode="Inline">    
    <AjaxSettings>                    
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="MyControl">                
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="MyOtherControl" />
            </UpdatedControls>          
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>    
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

It looks like the second `RadAjaxPanel` is just setting a fixed width. Just use a regular `Panel` or a DIV for this and you should be all set.

Comment: I'm not sure of the technical reason behind it not working, but I know that's not how they're supposed to be used, especially without some kind of valid reason to warrant it.